# Could someone recommend me a citable definition of honest but curious/semi-trusted?

Tags: trust, secret-sharing

As far as I know honest but curious or also called semi-trusted means that a client follows protocol but will try to learn as much information as possible, without actively “cheating”. Does anyone know a citable definition of this concept? Ideally one that I can look up online.

While looking for a source, I found many papers refer to Yao, but could not find a definition by him ("How to generate and exchange secrets" sadly is not available online)

Comment: Potentially relevant:Misuse vs Abuse  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57053/what-is-the-difference-between-misuse-and-abuse-cases-in-security

Answer (score 1):

I found a citable definition in "Modelling and Automatically Analysing Privacy
Properties for Honest-but-Curious Adversaries by Pavert" et al.

> The honest-but-curious (HBC) adversary is a legitimate participant in
>   a communication protocol who will not deviate from the defined
>   protocol but will attempt to learn all possible information from
>   legitimately received messages.

Answer (score 0):

An extensive textbook on cryptography with multiple references to semi-honest users, as well as half a chapter dedicated to it.

**Foundations of Cryptography: Volume 2 - Basic Applications**

**Author: Oded Goldreich**

*Section 7.1*

> An orthogonal parameter of restriction refers to whether a dishonest
>   party takes active steps to disrupt the execution of the protocol
>   (i.e., sends messages that differ from those specified by the
>   protocol), or merely gathers information (which it may later share
>   with the other dishonest parties). The latter adversary has been given
>   a variety of names, such as semi-honest, passive, and
>   honest-but-curious...

*Introduction to Section 7.2*

> In the first model, presented in Section 7.2.2, we consider a
>   restricted adversary called semi honest, whereas the general case of
>   malicious adversary is considered in Section 7.2.3. In addition to
>   being of independent interest, the semi-honest model will play a major
>   role in the constructions of protocols for the malicious model (see
>   Sections 7.3 and 7.4).

*Section 7.2.2. The Semi-Honest Model*

> Loosely speaking, a semi-honest party is one who follows the protocol
>   properly with the exception that it keeps a record of all its intermediate 
>   computations.

...

> ...semi-honest parties in our exposition, they do constitute a model
>   of independent interest. In particular, deviation from the specified
>   program...

also

*A Note on the Relation between the Definitions of Security for Semi-Honest and Malicious Adversaries*, a paper by *Carmit Hazay and Yehuda Lindell*, reference the above textbook when discussing semi-honest.